# Deserialize json array and object to strings with default GSON configuration

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to deserialize json like this:

```
{
    "key1" : [
        {
            "hash1" : "value1_1",
            "hash2" : "value1_2",
            ...
            "hashN" : "value1_3",
            "date" : "dateValue1"
        },
        {
            "hash1" : "value2_1",
            "hash2" : "value2_2",
            ...
            "hashN" : "value2_3",
            "date" : "dateValue2"
        }, 
        ...
    ],
    "key2": {
        "description" : {
              "hash1" : {
                 "description1" : "some text",
                 "description2" : "some text",
              },
              ...
              "hashN" : {
                 "description1" : "some text",
                 "description2" : "some text",
              }
         }
    }
}
```

That json have set of unknow keys: hash1, hash2, ... hash2, and set of know keys: key1, key2, description, date, description1, description2.

I work with some custom rest client which use default GSON configuration to deserialize jsons to objects. And I can't change that configuration.
Using this rest client looks like this:

```java
restClient.makeRequest(requestData, DataResponse.class, new RestResponseListener<DataResponse>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccessfulResponse(DataResponse responseData)
            {
            }
        });
```

DataResponse class have to inherit from Response class from rest client package.
That rest client can't deserialize jsons like above so I decide to try deserializing to String or JsonObject and next in `onSuccessfulResponse` use custom deserializer.

I try to create below class to hold response:

```java
public class DataResponse extends Response
{
    private String key1;
    private String key2;

    public DataResponse()
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get exception:

```java
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 14 path
```

The question is, how to deserialize array from key1 and object from key2 to strings.

Or maybe is another solution.

Comment: Why do you need them to be strings?

Comment: I wonted to use that strings with gson in onSuccessfulResponse method: `gson.fromJson(responseData.key1, MyData.class);`, where gson instance would be created from GsonBuilder with appropriate TypeAdapter.

Comment: Try to change the types of fields to `JsonElement` -- this class is also Gson-friendly: Gson will create internal JSON trees and you can delegate them downstream. However, why not just make these fields `MyData` and _your another class_ respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Lyubomyr Shaydariv advice I found two solutions.

#### Using JsonElement class

`JsonElement` is of course abstract so I have to use subclasses as below

```
public class DataResponse extends Response
{
    private JsonArray key1;
    private JsonObject key2;

    public DataResponse()
    {
    }
    //getters
}
```

In rest client callback I handled this data like this:

```java
restClient.makeRequest(requestData, DataResponse.class, new RestResponseListener<DataResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessfulResponse(DataResponse responseData)
        {
            Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for(JsonElement element : responseData.getKey1())
            {
                  Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(element, mapType);
                  //do things
            }
        }
    });
```

#### Match DataResponse class to json structure

I don't know why it doesn't work previously, but now does:

```java
public class DataResponse extends Response
{
    private List<Map<String, String>> key1;
    private Key2SchemaClass key2;

    public DataResponse()
    {
    }

    public static class Key2SchemaClass
    {
         private List<Map<String, Description>> description;
    }
    public static class Description
    {
         private String description1;
         private String description2;
    }
    //getters
}
```